# Change the font weight of the value checked by a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of dynamically retrieved files and they are appended with radio buttons using javascript. I have an option to check on that file and click on a button for example Activate. I want to change the font-weight of the checked button indicating that file is activated. How do I do this using javascript?

Here is the javascript that I have written:

```
function activateFile(){
            var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
            checkboxes = table.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i+=2) {
                if( checkboxes[i].checked == true){
                    //Send the file to the server to activate(I have this        functionality)
                    // Then change the font-weight of activated file on the client side                     
                    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
          }
}
```

I dont understand how I can change the font weight to bold.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: What is the HTML mark up?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this purely with CSS, but you need to wrap the text of each input in a span or other tag:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"><label>Milk</label><br>
```

Then just use the sibling selector:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: You should use a label and not a span.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned code but here the code which u can use:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input:radio[name=M/F]:checked').change(function () {
                if ($("input[name='M/F']:checked").val() == 'Male') {
                   $('.lblfontChange').css("font-size", "14 px");
                }
                if ($("input[name='M/F']:checked").val() == 'female') {
                    $('.lblfontChange').css("font-size", "10 px");
                }
            });
        });
```